# Ignore order of elements using xs:extension

Tags: xml, xsd

How can I design my *xsd* to ignore the sequence of elements?

```
<root> <a/> <b/> </root>
```

```
<root> <b/> <a/> </root>
```

---

I need to use [`extension`](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_extension.asp) for code generation reasons, so I tried the following using [`all`](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_all.asp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/test"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:t="http://www.example.com/test" >

    <xs:complexType name="BaseType">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ExtendedType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="t:BaseType">
                <xs:all> <!-- ERROR -->
                    <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:all>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="root" type="t:ExtendedType"></xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

This xsd is not valid though, the following error is reported at `<!-- ERROR -->`:

> cos-all-limited.1.2: An all model group must appear in a particle with {min occurs} = {max occurs} = 1, and that particle must be part of a pair which constitutes the {content type} of a complex type definition.

Documentation of [cos-all-limited.1.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cos-all-limited) says:

> 1.2 the {term}  property of a particle with {max occurs}=1 which is part of a pair which constitutes the {content type}  of a complex type definition.

I don't really understand this (*neither xsd nor English native speaker :)* ).

---

Am I doing the wrong thing, am I doing the right thing wrong, or is there no way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**MAJOR EDIT** Originally I missed the requirement that you need to use `xsd:extension`. Note that `xsd:extension` works as if there was `xsd:sequence` with contents of the base type followed by contents of the extended type.  As XML Schema Primer puts it:

> When a complex type is derived by
>   extension, its effective content model
>   is the content model of the base type
>   plus the content model specified in
>   the type derivation. Furthermore, the
>   two content models are treated as two
>   children of a sequential group.

Therefore, it seems that the only way to make this work is to have an empty base type and store the whole alternative in the extended type, or vice versa (everything in the base and an empty extension).  Like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="ExtendedType">
   <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="BaseType">
         <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="a" type="xsd:string"/>
               <xsd:element name="b" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="b" type="xsd:string"/>
               <xsd:element name="a" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:extension>
   </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="BaseType"/>

<xsd:element name="root" type="ExtendedType"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your update. Unfortunately I need to define some elements in the base type, and some in the extended, so unless there is another way, the elements of the extended type will always have to be placed after the elements of the base type...

Comment: @Peter In that case, since "two content models are treated as two children of a sequential group", there is no way (as far as I can see) to ignore the sequence.

Comment: I already assumed that... Maybe someone else has any ideas, otherwise I am gonna stick with my solution and force the "correct" sequence of the elements. Thanks for your time, really appreciated!

Comment: yes but if I have more that then element, how could I write this?

Comment: @Bolo So you have to list all possible orderings of the elements in their own sequence? If you had 5 elements, you'd have to have to define all 120 sequences??

Answer (score 6):

Here is the explanation of the restriction:
http://marc.info/?l=xerces-j-user&m=118712527901786&w=4

The only extension you can make to complex type with an "all" model is to add some attributes. You can't extend with new elements.

In my case I've done something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/test"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:t="http://www.example.com/test" >

    <xs:complexType name="BaseType">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ExtendedType">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" /> <!-- copy/paste from BaseType -->
            <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="root" type="t:ExtendedType"></xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<xs:complexType name="BaseType"> 
    <xs:sequence> 
        <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" /> 
    </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType> 

<xs:complexType name="ExtendedType"> 
    <xs:complexContent> 
        <xs:extension base="t:BaseType"> 
            <xs:sequence> 
                <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" /> 
            </xs:sequence> 
        </xs:extension> 
    </xs:complexContent> 
</xs:complexType> 

<xs:element name="root" type="t:ExtendedType"></xs:element>
```

Comment: @Ruslan: Have you tried this? It will enforce the sequence of `a` before `b`, so it does not actually help me...