# XSD Validation error using extension and all indicator

Tags: validation, xsd, unordered

I'm try to validate the following schema that use schema extension and all indicator:

```
001 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
002 <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://myschemas.com/test" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    targetNamespace="http://myschemas.com/test">
003 <xsd:complexType name="baseClass">
004  <xsd:all>
005   <xsd:element name="field1" type="xsd:string"/>
006  </xsd:all>
007 </xsd:complexType>
008 <xsd:complexType name="derivedClass">
009  <xsd:complexContent>
010   <xsd:extension base="tns:baseClass">
011     <xsd:all>      <!-- Fails with error: cos-all-limited.1.2 -->
012     <xsd:element name="extField2" type="xsd:string"/>
013    </xsd:all>
014   </xsd:extension>
015  </xsd:complexContent>
016 </xsd:complexType>
017 </xsd:schema>
```

The schema validation fails at line 011 with the following error:
"*cos-all-limited.1.2: An all model group must appear in a particle with {min occurs} = {max occurs} = 1, and that particle must be part of a pair which constitutes the {content type} of a complex type definition.*"
Anybody can help me if it's possible to continuing use the schema extension for an undefined elements order using the all indicator "<all>" because I don't need to specify the exact elements order?

Thank you in advance. Massimo

Comment: You can't extend `all` with new elements. See some alternatives here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689579/ignore-order-of-elements-using-xsextension

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808156/xsd-how-to-extend-a-type-with-an-unordered-list-of-elements

Comment: See the better answer below...  Difference between schema 1.0 and 1.1

Answer (score 2):

You'll need XML Schema 1.1 to add elements via extension to an `xsd:all` content model.  If you can live with an imposed element ordering, you can use `xsd:sequence` instead with either XSD 1.0 or 1.1.

### XML Schema 1.0

See [XML Schema Part 1: Structures Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/), section [2.2.1.3 Complex Type Definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Complex_Type_Definition):

> Note: This specification allows only appending, and not other kinds of
>   extensions. This decision simplifies application processing required
>   to cast instances from derived to base type. Future versions may allow
>   more kinds of extension, requiring more complex transformations to
>   effect casting.

### XML Schema 1.1

See [W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD) 1.1 Part 1: Structures](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/), section [2.2.1.3 Complex Type Definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#Complex_Type_Definition):

> Note: For the most part, this specification allows only appending, and
>   not other kinds of extensions. This decision simplifies application
>   processing required to cast instances from the derived type to the
>   base type. One special case allows the extension of all-groups in ways
>   that do not guarantee that the new material occurs only at the end of
>   the content. Another special case is extension via Open Contents in
>   interleave mode.

### See also

Per @[helderdarocha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3190413/helderdarocha)'s comments, be sure to also see:

- [xsd: How to extend a type with an unordered list of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3808156/290085)
- [Ignore order of elements using xs:extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2689579/290085)

Comment: There are other questions around Stackoverflow that leave 1.1 out.  Very surprised that this did not have an up vote yet.

Comment: Note though that XSD 1.1 is [not available in core java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31889170/411282)